# Increment Key-Value from a for loop to a map

Tags: kotlin, mapping

I have this map

```
    var alphabet= mutableMapOf("a" to 1)
```

And i would like to add from a for loop all the letters of the alphabet and their numbers.
For example:
a=1
b=2
...
z=26

How can i **add ++** to keys and values in a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate over chars range:

```
val alphabet = mutableMapOf<Char, Int>()
for (c in 'a'..'z') {
    alphabet[c] = c - 'a' + 1;
}
```

Also if you are not planning to change this map after initialization I do not think you really need a map here, just a function for `c - 'a' + 1` with proper range checks will be enough.

Comment: Thank you very much!I just wanted to learn maps that's why i needed to do it in that way :)

Comment: @AlexKolydas your comment makes me wondering... what exactly did you want to learn regarding maps? If you just wanted to create a new alphabet-map that could have also been done using: `('a'..'z').associateWith { it - 'a' + 1 }`...